# assign row number for datatable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have table to save seat plan for students of different levels.
Suppose 5 students of level 1 are assigned in room 1 .For that row number will be 1 to 5 .
Other 5 students of same level are assigned in room2,
For this row number must be 6 to 10.I am using
   `<h:outputText value= "#{rowIndex+1}"/>`
 to show row number. But using this ,row number is again 1 to 5.
 How to do so?? My code is like this.

```
<p:dataTable id="tblStudents" style="margin-top:4px"
                            value="#{seatPlanGenerationMB.lstRegistration}"
                            selection="#{seatPlanGenerationMB.lstSelectedExamRegistration}"
                            paginator="true" rows="20"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="20,40,60" rowIndexVar="rowsn" var="student"
                            resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="230"
                            rowKey="#{student.registrationId}" rowStyleClass="#{rowsn le 1975 ? 'colored' : null}">
                            <p:column width="15">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.sn}" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{rowsn+1}" style="float:right;" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Reg No." width="20"
                                style="text-align:center">
                                <h:outputText value="#{student.stuLevelModel.regNo}"
                                    style="float:right;" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Student Name" width="50">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{student.stuLevelModel.studentModel.studentName}" />
                            </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="subject" width="70">
                                <h:outputText value="#{student.examSubModel.subjectName}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Paper" width="20">
                                <h:outputText value="#{student.testpaperCodevaluModel.cvLbl==null?'':student.testpaperCodevaluModel.cvLbl}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column style="text-align:center" selectionMode="multiple"
                                width="10">
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

if 5 students of level 1 have been saved then while loading data of same level in room 2 ,row number must start from 6 .

My code to load combo is like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Level  *" style="font-weight:bold;" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="cmbLevel"   value="#seatPlanGenerationMB.levelModel.levelId}"
        required="true" style="width:180px;">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Level" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{examSubjectMB.level}" var="level"
        itemValue="#{level.levelId}" itemLabel="#{level.name}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{seatPlanGenerationMB.loadLevelwise()}" process="cmbLevel"   update="tblStudents :messageGrowl" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I fail to see the problem. Show code

Comment: I still fail to see the problem. I don't see how the code example you posted results in a repeating row index in the datatable. That cannot happen.

Comment: With above code,the row number again starts from 1

Comment: i have to count the students for level 1 that have been saved  and while displaying the students in datatable for room 2, the row number must start from count value +1.

Comment: There is only one datatable in your code.

Comment: In this form i have two combos one to select room and another to select level. According to the selection of level Combo I have loaded data in that datatable according to the room capacity.if the data is already saved in database ,the data is not shown in the datatable.i.e if i have saved students from 1 to 5 in room 1 then  while  selecting same level   to  assign other students in room 2,the datatable must display students that are not saved and the row value must start from 6 but not 1.

Comment: The datatable cannot do this for you. To complicated. You have to keep an kind of offset in the model and add the rowindex to that

Comment: Thank you for your help.